# Working in London in IT without a degree

Tags: software-industry, job-search, united-kingdom, project-management, developer

I recently had a Swiss Superior School Diploma in Computer Management (Informatique de Gestion in french). It took 2 years with 9 weeks internship in an IT company.

I've been thinking about working in London for a while now but I'm not sure if I should wait until I have a bachelor. Like lots of countries having a Degree is apparently quite normal to have in the UK.

After a year in this company that finally employed me as a developer I could apply for a job in London or enter in a University in Geneva and move to London later.

I really want to move to London but I'm not sure if there are opportunities for people like me from as far as I know.

Thanks for you advices.

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

Some companies will want evidence of academic achievement.  Some will use degree level education as a way of reducing the numbers of applications (preferring a higher quality and less quantity).  Some companies will look at any relevant experience.

It also depends on what level of job you're after and the companies you're applying too.  Banks will look for more qualifications than a start-up.

All you can do is look for job listing for your chosen level/role and see what qualifications are requested and work from there.

Comment: "_Some companies will look at any relevant experience._" So IT developer don't have to have a degree for some companies. Thanks !